# Webpage Header And Footer Overflowing Off Page

Tags: html, css

I just came across this issue where by my webpage is extending itself despite the fact that all the components that are forcing the page bigger are having the width value as 100% in the CSS. All the code below is linked to both the header and footer which are the main culprits to the issue.

HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
            <a href="index.html">
        <img src="images/logo.png" title="AccountPanda" style="width:225px;height:75px;">
            </a>    
            <li><a href="#">ACCOUNTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>    
    </ul>   


<footer>
    <img src="images/logo.png" style="height:60px" class="logofooter">
    <p class="copyright">&copy; Copyright 2017 ACCOUNTPARADISE</p>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
.nav {
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 20px;

}
.nav > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.nav > li > a:hover {
    color: #D9D9D9;
}


footer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}     

.copyright {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 0.30cm;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Works for me. Nothing going past page. Is this happening on a specific browser or device?

Comment: Im on Chrome right now on my PC, 21.5 inch monitor

Comment: Maybe set body with and margins to 0

Comment: Without being able to reproduce the problem I can only suggest adding the style * { outline: 1px solid red } and narrowing down the culprit further in dev tools

Comment: @Forcefield I already had this set